How to Deploy a Pre-Built Flask App to Cloudflare Pages from a Specific Directory
I've built a Flask web app and deployed it to GitHub. To create a static version for faster loading and easier hosting, I've used Flask-Frozen to generate static files in a build/ directory.
I want to deploy this static site to Cloudflare Pages, directly from the build/ directory. I've set up a Cloudflare Pages project connected to my GitHub repository. However, it seems to be deploying the files from the root directory.
How can I configure Cloudflare Pages to deploy the content from the build/ directory instead?
I'm building the build/ directory locally before pushing to GitHub.
Any guidance or specific configuration steps would be greatly appreciated.
